# Compile standalone Windows .exe using MATLAB on a mac

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, mcc

I am currently using this code to compile a standalone .app file of a MATLAB GUI on my mac:

```
mcc -m eotvos.m -a ./*
```

This works perfectly and I have a fully-functional mac executable. Is there a way to create a windows executable on my mac? I know that code works within MATLAB on windows. Is there a way to create a .exe file on my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware this is not possible.  It is possible to cross compile between 32bit/64bit on the same OS but not between OS's.  Though I cant find it explicitly in the docs at the moment.  Will update if I do.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for the help, dgorissen! I guess I will just have to use a PC to compile it. Thanks again, -Alex.